# Can the chocolatey/choco container be used on Apple M1 Silicon?

Tags: apple-m1, podman, chocolatey

Morning, I have been attempting for the last few hours to get chocolatey linux docker image to build and run using podman (v 4.2.1) on Apple M1 Silicon (macOS v13.4); however every attempt to use the choc command from the build egine results in an apparent mono error

```
* Assertion at ../../mono/arch/amd64/../x86/x86-codegen.h:410, condition `offset == (gint32)offset' not met
```

Can anyone provide any insights as to the problem?

The image appears to build/run correctly; however, when attempting to use a bash shell and execute any choco command results in the above error. I have also tried to used the chocalatey image as a base image and simply build the cmds inside a docker file...however, I get the following error

```
    =================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
/usr/local/bin/choco: line 3:     3 Aborted                 (core dumped) mono /opt/chocolatey/choco.exe "$@"
```

Comment: Isn't Chocolatey a package manager for Windows?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is, but certain commands can be used with Mono, so that folk can pack and push packages from build systems etc.  

That said, I'm not familiar with the differences when running on Apple's silicon, and I don't think anyone on the team has access to such a device. [This issue](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21423) seems to match up, mostly?

Comment: To be clear, @jlockhart, choco commands from within the container are failing but the container is building and starting successfully? (I am slightly confused by the last line)

Comment: @JamesRuskin added some clarifying info...does that address your questions?